# How can i change the width and height of an image inside a <source> element?

Tags: html, css

For example:

```
<picture> 

<source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="mycat.jpg">
<source media="min-width:460px)" srcset="burncar.jpg">
<img src="burncar2.jpg" style="width:auto;">

</picture>
```

Now, the srcset image loads in full size. How do i change its size? I tried adding "width" and "height" within the  element, but it doesn't work. I tried adding a Class inside the  element and then target it in CSS to change the size, but again it didn't work. Why? And how do i change the size of the pictures?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `@media` in CSS matching your source media min-width.  Look at what I did in this example. Here's the jsfiddle for you to play around with the screen size. https://jsfiddle.net/ukwhn8p1/4/

```css
@media (min-width: 460px) {
  .pictures {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 650px) {
  .pictures {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<picture>
<source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_white_flower.jpg">
<source class="flower" media="(min-width:460px)" srcset="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pink_flowers.jpg">
<img class="pictures" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" style="">
</picture>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have few questions though. First of all, what are you targeting with the @ media selector? Also, in your example, there is only one <img> element, what if i have many, and need to specify with a class? How do i use the class in the css with the @ media selector? Also, i don't understand why is last element in the <picture> tag always an <img> wheres the others are <source>?

Comment: I've updated my answer to do it by class and not just `img`  You need the `img` at the bottom because that is where the source will be applied to for the `picture` if you remove the `img` in the `picture` it won't have anything to apply the source to.  The @media is targeting the media with the widths I've have called out.  when the screen hits that width, then the media changes.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle to further demonstrate the classes and how things work.  https://jsfiddle.net/eay2pwdn/

Comment: I think i got it now. Your examples were very useful. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am sorry i have one more quick question. In w3school it says that, if the img format is not supported, the browser will use the first available format that it supports among the picture sources. I tried making the img format one that isn't supported, but i also made the first picture source a format that wasn't supported, and only left the second picture source a supported format. The browser didn't load the second source picture, it just kept showing that the first one is not supported. Why is that? Also, why did you use a class flower in the source element?

Comment: I think the source in the img might need to be a correct format. Also that flower class doesn't do anything. I was playing around with the code and left it in on accident. You can remove it.

Comment: It's not working. I am really confused about this. Here's my simple code: 

<picture> 

<source srcset="carbnp.bnp" alt="first source">
<source srcset="mycat.jpg" alt="second source">
<img src="burncar.jpg" alt="img">

</picture>

The image inside the first source element is not supported, the second one is, and the img element picture is also supported. When i run this, the first image doesn't open, so the img element pic should open, but it doesn't, the alt title is showing, while the image isn't. Why isn't the img pic showing, and why isn't the second source pic showing?

Comment: update: I just realized i have made few mistakes. First of all, to make it clear, i am not adding a min-width to the 2 <source> elements because that's how it's shown to work in w3school. Second, when the first <source> image does not load, the browser does not skip to the <img> element, instead it just stays with that first <source> pic and keeps showing the alt name specified in the <img> element. IF however, i add min-width to the first <source>, then once the browser hits that width, the second <source> pic opens. However, that is not how w3school says it's supposed to work.

Comment: According to them, when the first <source> does not open because the image has a format not supported by the browser, the "next available picture should open" among the <source> elements. That is not happening in my example. The first <source> element has a not supported format, and the browser does not open the next available one, or even the <img> element pic, which is also supported, instead it just stays like that and displays the alt name. Here's the w3school page: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_picture.asp Are they wrong, or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What i tend to do to size images is to put a `<div class="image_container">` around the image. Setting the width for the container makes the picture to always load at that width.

Sometimes 'weird' behavior can turn up due to weird image heights, but that tends to only be the case with images you can't control the source of (aka. some internet image from a link to it, or some upload). Same is obviously true if you only set the height.

Setting both the width and height can distort an image, as it is made to fit the size of the parent (aka. the image_container).

Cool thing about this though, is that you can set min and max widths for the container and get pretty decent control over the reactivity of the design based upon view or window size.

If you can control the actual source of the image (aka. you control the initial width and height), or you can account for deviations in either width or the height in your design. This  works satisfactory.